# Hyperledger Composer - NetworkAdmin#admin has no READ access to network

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Upon following this tutorial https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-blockchain-network-using-hyperledger-fabric-and-composer-e06644ff801d

When I use the command:

```
composer network start --networkName my-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file my-network-admin.card
```

I successfully create the card and import it using the following command:

```
composer card import --file my-network-admin.card
```

However, the problem is using the following command:

```
composer network ping --card admin@my-network
```

I receive the following error:

> transaction returned with failure: AccessException: Participant 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin' does not have 'READ' access to resource 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#my-network@0.0.1'
>   Command failed

I've looked at the documentation and tried restarting the entire process a couple of times to no avail. I even tried adding the following to my `permissions.acl` file:

```
/*
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

rule Default {
description: "Grant all access by default"
participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
operation: ALL
resource: "**"
action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminUser {
description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
operation: ALL
resource: "**"
action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
operation: ALL
resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
action: ALLOW
}
```

**EDIT:**

When I run `composer card list -c admin@my-network`, I get the following:

```
userName:            admin
description:         
businessNetworkName: my-network
identityId:          fc63d3e4b3b3d73a2be2943a0c422e7af862207f9489fc1ce3707e8769efc99b
roles: 
  - PeerAdmin
connectionProfile: 
  name:   hlfv1
  x-type: hlfv1
credentials:         Credentials set

Command succeeded
```